# Running ajax call on specific form name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I just wanted to know how I can run a function on a specific form name? instead of just any form.. my code is below you don't really need to know anything else, its for an ajax call.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo $config['website']['url']; ?>/assets/hk/ajax/muteorban.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              var div = document.getElementById('contentArea_muteorban');
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data;
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use name selector `$('form[name="myFormName"]')` as follows :

```
$('form[name="myFormName"]').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo $config['website']['url']; ?>/assets/hk/ajax/muteorban.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(), ///////// <<<<<<<<<<<<< you can use $(this) here
            success: function (data) {
              var div = document.getElementById('contentArea_muteorban');
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data;
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

Comment: This question should **not** be answered and rather be closed as a duplicate.